# while loop not incrementing and displaying a NaN in conjunction with my round timer

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have this martial arts scoreboard project set up (at the moment) to run a 3-second round, and a 2-second rest period in-between rounds, and for it to change rounds to the next round. The rounds should start at 1, and not pass 3 rounds. At the moment, the while loop changes rounds to the 2nd round, but it does not change to a third round. It displays a "NaN" in the seconds area and does not move the match into a 3rd round. I'm sure it's something small, but I can't seem to figure it out. To make it easier for those helping me, I have displayed my GitHub repository below, and the URL where it's currently live to see the error at hand. Thanks in advance.

```
let interval;
let roundNumbers = 1;

function countdownBreak() {
  while (roundNumbers <= 3) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      var timer = $(".time-clock-break").html();
      timer = timer.split(":");
      var minutes = timer[0];
      var seconds = timer[1];
      seconds -= 1;
      if (minutes < 0) return;
      else if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
        minutes -= 0;
        seconds = 2;
      } else if (seconds < 10 && length.seconds != 2) seconds = "0" + seconds;

      $(".time-clock-break").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);

      if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        roundNumbers++;
        console.log(roundNumbers);
        document.querySelector(".round-number").textContent = roundNumbers;
        document.querySelector(".time-clock").textContent = "0:03";
        document.querySelector("#timer").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
      }
      if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 10) {
        playAudioRumble();
      }
    }, 1000);
    break;
  }
}
```

GitHub Repository: https://github.com/jaredantonreed/martial-arts-scoreboard 
Live Version: https://jaredreed.dev/javascript/martial-arts-scoreboard/

Answer (score 0):

first error length.seconds it should be seconds.length
and while loop is not the best at all it exit to early

here a proper version of  a loop lets me know if its work

```
let interval;
let roundNumbers = 1;

function countdownBreak() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function () {
    var timer = $(".time-clock-break").html();
    timer = timer.split(":");
    var minutes = timer[0];
    var seconds = timer[1];
    seconds -= 1;
    if (minutes < 0) return;
    else if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
      minutes -= 0;
      seconds = 2;
    } else if (seconds < 10 && seconds.length != 2) seconds = "0" + seconds;

    $(".time-clock-break").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);

    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      roundNumbers++;
      console.log(roundNumbers);
      if (roundNumbers <= 3) {
        document.querySelector(".round-number").textContent = roundNumbers;
        document.querySelector(".time-clock").textContent = "0:03";
        document.querySelector("#timer").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
        countdown();
      }
    }
    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 10) {
      playAudioRumble();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function countdown() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function () {
    var timer = $(".time-clock").html();
    timer = timer.split(":");
    var minutes = timer[0];
    var seconds = timer[1];
    seconds -= 1;
    if (minutes < 0) return;
    else if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
      minutes -= 1;
      seconds = 59;
    } else if (seconds < 10 && seconds.length != 2) seconds = "0" + seconds;

    $(".time-clock").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);

    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      countdownBreak();
      document.querySelector("#timer").style.color = "#FF0000";
      playAudioBell();
    }
    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 10) {
      playAudioRumble();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

countdownBreak();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, your solution did not work, and I still experience the same error. It did however, point me into a thought I did not have that the loop does seem to be exiting too early, and does not trigger two things: 
1. The seconds in between rounds. This does not start after the second round ends. After the first round ends, you will notice that "0:02" displays. After the second round, this does not display. 
2. The "loop" moving into round 3.

Comment: did u still get NaN ?

Comment: Yes, I still got NaN.